# How to listen the event from server without web-socket

Tags: javascript, node.js, https

I want to implement one validation feature where the client submits some data like CSV files. And the server will do the validations.
Validations are done in multiple stages each stage can take a variable amount of time to validate. Whenever the server completes one validation step, it should send it to the client, so that I can show it to the user in UI.

What should be the better way to do it?

I don't want to use WebSocket, as this is the only feature using that and it will be momentary.

I also don't want to have long polling as it will keep the server busy unnecessary.

I want something like firebase HTTPS polling it keeps open for a while and discards it every 3 sec, and in between keep listening to the server. But I don't know how to implement it.

Also if the answer is a keep-alive HTTPS connection. Not sure how to write code for that either. So the example in React/JS and the node can be very helpful.

Comment: [Server-sent events?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events).

Comment: Thanks, @Andy this could help.  I never heard of this feature before, but looking at the doc I think it can work for my use case.

Comment: Just because you only want to use the feature temporarily does not mean that webSocket wouldn't be a good choice.  The client can make the connection just for the duration of this process and then close it when complete.  Creating a webSocket connection is just an http request - it's not a heavyweight thing at all.  Or, if one-way communication is fine, you can use server-sent events which is essentially a lasting http connection.  If you're avoiding polling, then webSocket and server-sent-events are you two best chocies.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [rejax.io](https://rejax.io) api service which you can make http post request to it with a message that will be broadcasted to client(s) for you. I am author.

- register for a free api key
- include client script for clients
- make (from server) http post request to service with message
- message is broadcasted immediately to clients
- your server continues with processing

client code:

```
Rejax.listen('my-channel-name', function(text) {
    // received text from server
    console.log(text)
})
```

server code:

```
const axios = require('axios')
axios
    .post('https://rejax.io:3001/api/server', {
        'app_key' : 'MY_APP_KEY',
        'app_secret' : 'MY_APP_SECRET',
        'channel' : 'my-channel-name',
        'text' : 'hello from server'
    })
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error)
    })
```